# Looping through and parsing JSON objects within arrays that are stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to obtain the email from my users by looping through and parsing stringified arrays containing an object within local storage.

```
User1632925384043: "[{\"first\":\"James\",\"last\":\"Chen\",\"email\":\"jchen@gmail.com\",\"pass\":\"2222222222222222222\"}]"
User1632982295360: "[{\"first\":\"Sarah\",\"last\":\"Jones\",\"email\":\"sj@gmail.com\",\"pass\":\"444444444444444444\"}]"
```

With the way my data is being stored, I'm having a hard time traversing through the objects and grabbing the data I want.

With a simple array containing an object, I would do something like this to grab the email -

```
const employees = [
    {
        name: "Harri",
        email: "hgreeves@protonmail.com",
        role: "English Teacher"
    }
]

const emails = () => {
    employees.forEach(employee => {
        // console.log(employee.email);
        return employee.email;
    })
}
```

But in this case, having the objects stored in local storage adds another layer (the local storage object).

Also, trying to `JSON.parse()` the data returns this error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Say if I remove `JSON.parse`, with this code -

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem(key));
    const user = localStorage.getItem(key);
    for (const prop in user) {
        console.log(`${prop}: ${user[prop]}`);
    }
 });
```

I then end up looping through each individual character of the key value pairs e.g. -

```
11: S
sign-in.js:42 12: a
sign-in.js:42 13: r
sign-in.js:42 14: a
sign-in.js:42 15: h
sign-in.js:42 16: "
sign-in.js:42 17: ,
sign-in.js:42 18: "
sign-in.js:42 19: l
sign-in.js:42 20: a
sign-in.js:42 21: s
sign-in.js:42 22: t
sign-in.js:42 23: "
sign-in.js:42 24: :
sign-in.js:42 25: "
sign-in.js:42 26: J
sign-in.js:42 27: o
sign-in.js:42 28: n
sign-in.js:42 29: e
sign-in.js:42 30: s
```

As you'd expect, I don't want to loop through every character. I want to loop through the keys in my object so I can obtain the email.

I also don't understand the ```/''' within my objects and whether or not it's affecting my ability to navigate through them.

This data is collected from user inputs -

```
const saveUser = () => {
    inputs = [signUpForm.querySelectorAll(".signUpInput")].map(input => {
        first = firstName.value;
        last = lastName.value;
        email = signUpEmail.value;
        pass = signUpPass.value;

        return { first, last, email, pass }
    });
        // sets unique user
        localStorage.setItem("User" + new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(inputs));
        data.email = email;
        data.pass = pass;
        users.push(data);
        // console.log(users);
        data = {};
};
```

Can I/should I retrieve the data I want when it's stored in this way? Or do I need to change how it's being stored?

If having the data stored like this is okay, how can I parse it then retrieve it without receiving an error?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` and find out why it errors. Print the the data with `console.log()` first to see if it is valid JSON.

Comment: And don't use generated keys in the localStorage, you won't be able to find the data anymore afterwards. You can also just store all items in an array.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What are generated keys exactly? Yeah I plan to store all this data in an array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use

you have do only one foreach loop remove for loop inside of foreach

```
Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
console.log(localStorage.getItem(key));
const user = localStorage.getItem(key);

console.log(user[0].email);
```

});

Comment: Thanks. This brings up ```[{"first":"Sarah","last":"Jones","email":"sj@gmail.com","pass":"444444444444444444"}]``` in local storage. This is good but I'm still having trouble grabbing the email. E.g. with user.email or user[0].email they return undefined. Would I not need to JSON.parse(user) first? This also returns an error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). How do I grab the email here?

Comment: Okay , so now you can see result , that returning to you array with object, that containt data here what you should do next as example 


var objects =[{"first":"Sarah","last":"Jones","email":"sj@gmail.com","pass":"444444444444444444"}];



console.log(objects[0].email);

your result will be : sj@gmail.com

Comment: When you say 'objects', what text are you referring to exactly? E.g. If I use ```console.log(localStorage.getItem("User1632925368163")[0].email);```, it still returns undefined

Comment: you don't need to do this "localStorage.getItem("User1632925368163")[0].email);
you just need to get item look 
var user = localStorage.getItem("item_name);

console.log(user[0].email);

Comment: This will return undefined - ```const user =  localStorage.getItem("User1633265644366");
    console.log(user[0].email);```

Comment: check if is store to localStorage User1633265644366, maybe you not storing to local storage that why is undefine

Comment: Yeah it's in local storage

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, it may help you,

```
const saveUser = () => {
  let user = {};
  var inputs = [...signUpForm.querySelectorAll(".signUpInput")].forEach(input => {
    user[input.name] = input.value;
  });
  let currentUsers = localStorage.getItem("Users");
  currentUsers = !currentUsers ? currentUsers = [] : JSON.parse(currentUsers);
  currentUsers.push(user); //you can check whether this user exists and can update
  localStorage.setItem("Users", JSON.stringify(currentUsers));
};
const showSavedUsers = () => {
  let currentUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Users"));
  currentUsers.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.signUpEmail);
  });
}
saveUser();
showSavedUsers();
```